# Ошибка при запуске бота ubuntu

Tags: python

Запускаю бота на питоне в ubuntu, и вот такая ошибка, думаю не скачал какой-то модуль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я думаю это какой-то новый тренд выкладывать легко копируемый текст картинками.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: [importerror](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+importerror)